# Click in box with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[Web page inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZT8Q.png)

I want to click in the box and enter number with selenium python

how I can do that ?

and I want here to click in sign up:

[web page inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps98l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try these and am sure they would work
To click in the box and input a number you need to use driver.find_element_by_xpath('').sendkeys('then you input the number here')

For the clicking of signup you could also use driver.find_element_by_xpath('')